# Insert Data Attribute into Bootstrap 5 Popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, custom-data-attribute

I have a series of buttons that contain a data-attribute that I want to insert into the popover they toggle.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow btn-deleteTeacher" data-bs-toggle="popover" role="button" data-username="farkle86">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'top',
        content: "<a href='teachers.asp?action=delete&user="+$(this).data('username')+"'>Click Here</a> to permanently delete this teacher."
    });
```

When I hover over the text link in the popover, the variable is 'undefined'. I don't know how to properly acquire the username data attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within the `popover()` declaration isn't the element the `data` attribute exists on. To get a reference to the element you would need to loop through them manually when declaring the popovers:

```js
$('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').each((i, el) => {
  let $el = $(el);
  $el.popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'top',
    content: `<a href="teachers.asp?action=delete&user=${$el.data('username')}">Click Here</a> to permanently delete this teacher.`
  });
});
```

Comment: What if I targeted the ID or class of the button that was to toggle the popover?

Comment: will this work at all? bs5 has no jQuery dependency? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/

Comment: @Murphy1976 That would work too, but you'd need to copy this code for every `id` in the page, which would be a pain to maintain. The above works for anything given the data attribute

Comment: @naveen Bootstrap 5 still works with jQuery https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#still-want-to-use-jquery-its-possible

Comment: It's not dependant, but it still works

Comment: thanks. I didn't know. I thought it won't

Comment: @Rory McCrossan for this specific popover and message, it only applies to buttons that have the class .btn-deleteTeacher. But say I wanted to apply a general popover for all elements that have the data-bs-toggle="popover", in that EACH loop, I should be able to check if the element has that class, and then go from there, correct?

Comment: Yep - you just select the target elements in the initial jQuery object and loop over them.